# PHP MySQL add a empty raw between weeks on a table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a list of dates which fetched from mysql. and shows on a table like this

```
04-03-2013  
05-03-2013  
16-03-2013  
18-03-2013  
20-03-2013
01-04-2013
04-04-2013
05-04-2013
06-04-2013
```

i need to show a empty row between weeks on my table

ex

```
04-03-2013  
05-03-2013
--------------- 
16-03-2013  
18-03-2013  
20-03-2013
---------------
01-04-2013
04-04-2013
---------------
05-04-2013
06-04-2013
---------------
```

i tried some codes with PHP but no luck, any one know how to do this kind of thing. thank you

Comment: Share your php code here.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you trying to do? I can't see any patterns with your lines

Comment: use (int)date('W', $yourdate);

Answer (score 0):

while printing calculate the week of that particular day and store it in the array.For the next row onwards compare the values in the array using `in_arry()` with the calculated week if it is there just print the value if there is no value in the array push the value in to the array then print the line and print the value.

Comment: do you have some reference tutorials which i can follow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567673/get-week-number-in-the-year-from-a-date-php